# Running jar file on different machines/PCs

Tags: java

I have a jar file and a config file where both are in same directory. The jar file will read some values in the config file when it's running.

I ran my jar file on my command prompt. Everything works perfectly fine. So I decided to sent the same jar file and config file to another person to test in their pc using the same method. However, it doesn't work in his PC where he got this error:

```
D:\QA06122018_2>java -jar removeOldRecords.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
        at Indexing.remove_old_records(Indexing.java:229)
        at Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

It seems his pc couldn't read the config file.

Note: We both ran the same command and same files.

Is there a possible reason why it doesn't work on his pc?

EDIT:

The code to read the config file from jar:

```
 Properties props=new Properties();


        String path ="./config.properties";
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader in1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));


        props.load(in1);
        in1.close();
        int days=Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("value2"));
```

Comment: does he place config file and jar in same directory ?

Comment: Does the other person have the config file in the same folder as the jar?

Comment: Yes he place both in the SAME DIRECTORY. Is there anything wrong code wise?

Comment: it's not code, and are these two same OS or different OS?

Comment: The command is the same `java -jar removeOldRecords.jar`? If he run it with `java -jar /path/to/removeOldRecords.jar` it doesn't work because it doesn't find `config.properties`.

Comment: Please provide the JAVA version for the buggy PC. And is it the real code that you are using ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]  and the java version used on the bad pc

Answer (score 0):

Checking the method "java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine" in JDK_1.8.131, I didn't find a lot of solution that give a NPE.

The only way I was able to was to pass a `null` instance to the `Properties` constructor, which can't be with the code provided.

It would give another error if you close the reader sooner

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

If the file is not found :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./config.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Here is the only way I found to throw that NPE :

```
props.load((Reader) null);
```

The reason is simple, the instance `LineReader` only use two variables that are not primitive (or arrays)

- InputStream inStream;
- Reader reader;

The arrays are initialized in the constructors based on the instance received.

The rest is define in the instance so only these could be set to null based on what you pass to the constructor of `Properties`.

You can check for the file content using :

```
String s;
while((s =in1.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

(don't use the same reader to load the properties, you need to reopen a new one)

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to say

Comment: What I am saying @Daredevil is that based on what I see, it is not possible to create a NPE. But this is based on a specific JRE version.